# Create Timeseries chart with custom timestamp for custom events sent to New Relic

Tags: time-series, newrelic

I have some custom load test data, something like -

{“payload_size”: 15, “response_time”: 0.2, “timestamp”: 1670584754}

So i wanted to plot payload_size against timestamp as a timeseries chart, but the issue is I am sending all of this data in bulk, which may include 600 events like this (if ran for 10 minutes).

So when i do timeseries , it shows me one entry only as all the data is pushed at simple point of time.
Is there a workaround for this. I am using EventAPI to send all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can do this with New Relic's [custom visualizations](https://developer.newrelic.com/explore-docs/custom-viz/)

I wrote one specifically for this same use case here: https://github.com/khpeet/custom-timeseries

This allows you to plot your values on a timeseries chart with your own custom timestamp field. Note that `timestamp` is a reserved word in New Relic though, so you probably have to rename your timestamp key to something else upon posting the events via API.